# JavaScript sound library the doesn't require HTML 5 or Flash

Tags: javascript, flash, html, audio

Is there a reason that all of the audio javascript libraries I'm finding (jPlayer, SoundManager 2, etc.) try to use HTML 5, and if that doesn't work attempt to use Flash but then don't fall back to anything else?  Why wouldn't they try to fall back to the default HTML sound tags like `<embed>`, `<object>`, or `<bgsound>`?

Is there a library out there that does?  I'd like to be able to play a sound if the user is using IE6 without Flash installed.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `<embed>` or `<object>` unless a capable plugin is available.

Comment: Uh, since when are `<embed>`, `<object>`, and `<bgsound>` "default HTML sound tags"?  You have to give `<embed>` and `<object>` a plug-in to work with (that's where Flash comes into it) and `<bgsound>` is not part of any standard and only works in IE.

Comment: Serious question: IE6 without Flash Player installed? Considering IE6 has around 15% penetration, and Flash Player 9 has 99% penetration, do you really want to spend your time building something for 0.15% of the public? You may as well assume that those people don't even have speakers available. Unless you have a very specific target audience that will really be using MSIE6 without even the default plugins (some crazy government agency maybe), you'd better off just relying on Flash and HTML5 (for devices and OSs that don't have FP available).

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys.  I guess my understanding of those tags was incorrect!

Answer (score 0):

You can have it fallback so that if the person doesn't support HTML5 and you want to use basic HTML then just download a sound file and let the browser run an application to play it.

It isn't ideal, but as was pointed out, before HTML5 you have very few options, and since you don't like Flash your options just got reduced.

Comment: Midi files always used to work though didn’t they? 1996, home pages about cats and knitting, ‘The Greatest Love of All’ playing on midi as the hit counter gif clicks up deliberately to 00000008.

Comment: @Paul D. Waite - I expect most browsers will play midi files fine.